# Telethon: как правильно получить информацию о себе?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Хочу написать свой клиент для мессенджера Telegram на Python. Для этого использую библиотеку [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon). Беру пример кода с их главной страницы:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = my_id
api_hash = 'my_hash'

client = TelegramClient('Test2Session', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

print(client.get_me().stringify())
```

Этот код должен вывести в консоль информацию обо мне. При запуске этого кода получаю ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'stringify'
```

в строке

```
print(client.get_me().stringify())
```

Как исправить эту ошибку? Как получать информацию о себе?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно прописать просто без `.stringify()`:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = my_id
api_hash = 'my_hash'

client = TelegramClient('Test2Session', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
    print(client.get_me())
```